# Where can I get help for the problems for microsoft UWP sample?

Tags: uwp

I download UWP samples from:
https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples

I check some source codes and have some questions.
But I do not know who should I contact to get professional answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most of the API related information is well documented on MSDN so you'll get the required information. However in case of any issue/ bug related to sample you can directly raise on GitHub : https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/issues/new

Or, you can always use stackoverflow.